# MAXDATA parameter in 64-bit executables

Tags: aix

I had come to understand that setting -bmaxdata or LDR_CNTRL=MAXDATA... on AIX for 64-bit applications was only necessary to set a *limit* on the heap size of a process.  In other words, it was not necessary to raise any limits as it had been for 32-bit executables.

**On a particular AIX 7.1 system**, where `OBJECT_MODE=64 dump -ov my-executable` shows maxdata as 0x00000000 and LDR_CNTRL is not set, I have to set LDR_CNTRL=MAXDATA... to the 2GB-ish number we had been setting in our older 32-bit builds to be able to even initialize (initgroups() fails, pthread_create fails, etc) my 64-bit application.

Is there some case where setting MAXDATA is necessary in a 64-bit process to not have some ancient 256MB-ish cap on heap size?

```
# /usr/bin/ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         2097151
data(kbytes)         131072
stack(kbytes)        32768
memory(kbytes)       32768
coredump(blocks)     2097151
nofiles(descriptors) 2000
threads(per process) unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited

# OBJECT_MODE=64 dump -ov bin/httpd

bin/httpd:

                        ***Object Module Header***
# Sections      Symbol Ptr      # Symbols       Opt Hdr Len     Flags
         4      0x000c78b0           8683               120     0x1002
Flags=( EXEC DYNLOAD DEP_SYSTEM )
Timestamp = "Oct 05 19:03:19 2015"
Magic = 0x1f7  (64-bit XCOFF)

                        ***Optional Header***
Tsize       Dsize       Bsize       Tstart      Dstart
0x0007c66a  0x00009d06  0x00003c08  0x1000001f8  0x110000862

SNloader    SNentry     SNtext      SNtoc       SNdata
0x0004      0x0002      0x0001      0x0002      0x0002    

TXTalign    DATAalign   TOC         vstamp      entry
0x0007      0x0003      0x1100091b8  0x0001      0x110003a70

maxSTACK    maxDATA     SNbss       magic       modtype
0x00000000  0x00000000  0x0003      0x010b        1L
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limiting factor in your example is the ulimit 'data' value.  If set to 'unlimited' you will observe the expected output.

Comment: That does appear to be the case.  I guess LDR_CNTRL will lift it up to the hard limit implicitly, because setting both is not required

Comment: Just write a program that allocates 1MB in an infinite loop, and run it with different settings. In my experiments, I found two limit: 1. environment variable `LDR_CNTRL/MAXDATA`; 2. (if it is unset) `ulimit -d`. If the first is unset, and the second is `unlimited`, you will eat up the whole memory.